Dying boy is cryogenically frozen and attempts to kill his parents once revived
It was a story about a family and they had a son who was really sick. so the parents cryonically preserved the boy until they found a cure. 
after all, they found the cure and healed the boy and the boy brought back to life. but the problem is the boy felt deep solitude when he was cryopreserved and that solitude turn into hatred toward his parents, so after he revived he started to kill his parents. What is this movie?
Additionally, the boy was wearing a bow tie and kind of childish suit. and the family was rich. I remember the boy tries to shoot a gun to his parents. The family was white family.

Please tell us the genre, country, language, colour, age and anything else you remember about the plot or what the characters looked like.

Any idea of when it came out?

i don't.... i guess it's 2000' movie

A.I.? :p....................................

i'm big fan of a.l. so i totally know this is not a.l. lol

Could it be Wes Craven's Chiller (1985)? A TV movie that aired on CBS, it doesn't involve a child but does involved a man cryogenically frozen due to a then incurable condition who comes back wrong and turns on his parents. 
Summary:

Miles Creighton is cryonically preserved. When his storage tank malfunctions and begins to thaw, Miles is rushed to a hospital. His mother, who has missed her son terribly during his 10-year incapacitation, arranges for surgeons there to perform a procedure that was not possible when Miles was originally frozen. The operation is a success and Miles revives.
Miles returns to the company which his father (now deceased) had started. He ruthlessly strips down anything that the company does not require to be profitable, and fires the man responsible for keeping the company running in Miles' absence.
A series of mysterious deaths occur and circumstantial evidence implicates Miles. His mother, of course, does not want to believe her beloved son is a heartless killer. It is only when Father Penny (played by Paul Sorvino) arrives at the hospital in critical condition that she is convinced her son is evil. Penny tells her that Miles was responsible, and she rushes home to save her step daughter and have Miles arrested.
The events that follow pit Miles against his mother, and she ends up locking him in a walk-in freezer. The police arrive and discover that Miles, though apparently frozen, is still alive. His mother comes to the rescue by shooting her son in the chest with a police pistol.
The final scene is set at the cryogenics facility, where another alarm goes off as another storage tank malfunctions and begins to thaw. This is followed, by several more storage tank malfunctioning.


it's not chiller.... in that movie the boy was really young(around age 10 or younger) and the background was mostly his family's home.
